# UWP Typography recommendations do not seem to work

Tags: text, uwp, rendering, typography

I am building a UWP application and thought I should honor the Microsoft guidelines with respect to drawing my text. The full typography guidelines can be found at this [location](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/style/typography).

The guidelines specify the text size and line height. The line height should always be a multiple of 4, to enable good scaling behavior across device and screen sizes. Here is the guideline for the **Subtitle** text style: -

[image]

As can be seen the text size is 20 pixels and the line height 24. But if you create a **TextBlock** and use the provided **SubtitleTextBlockStyle** it does not draw correctly. Here is the code to test: -

```
<TextBlock Style="{ThemeResource SubtitleTextBlockStyle}"
           Text="SubtitleTextBlockStyle SubtitleTextBlockStyle SubtitleTextBlockStyle SubtitleTextBlockStyle"/>
```

You actually get text space at 26 and 27 pixels alternating: -

[image]

I tried setting the **Margin** and **Padding** of the **TextBlock** to zero and explicitly setting the **LineHeight** to be 24. It makes no difference.

It you place two **TextBlock** instances in a vertical **StackPanel** then you get a different spacing again, 28 pixels in line spacing between the two sets of text. To me it looks like the guidelines are impossible to actually implement.

Has anybody had any look implementing there own styles that match the guidelines? Or are they simply crap?

Comment: Have you tried setting `TextLineBounds` to `Tight`?

Comment: Looks promising, setting TextLineBounds=Tight and explicitly setting the LineHeight seems to allow the LineHeight to be applied correctly. Begs the question why the provided styles are wrong though.

Comment: I think the provided styles don't take the default spacing of the font into consideration. You will have to tweak those to get exactly what you need. But be careful as some of the properties will affect the performance of the rendering. So I normally only do this with titles and headings. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/text-block